# Using typescript, how to update HTML element's value and text.?

Tags: html, typescript

I want to update certain attributes of `html` element using typescript. Is it possible to do so? Here's my code

HTML:-

```
<a ref="#" id="userProfileName" style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px;">
<img src="" alt="" id="userProfilePic" class="profile-img" style="width: 56px; height: 50px;"></a>
```

Typescript:-

```
document.getElementById('userProfilePic').src = profile.picture;
document.getElementById('userProfileName').textContent = profile.given_name;
```

Error I'm getting:-

```
error TS2339: Property 'src' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [document.getElementById](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L7117) function returns an element of type [HTMLElement](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L8664) which does not have the `src` property.
You need to type assert it to [HTMLImageElement](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L9644):

```
(document.getElementById('userProfilePic') as HTMLImageElement).src = profile.picture;
```

The same goes for the [HTMLAnchorElement](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L8038) but `textContent` can be accessed straight from the `HTMLElement` so no need to cast.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you manipulate the HTMLElement from your Typescript file.
(Angular Framework)

HTML:

```
  <span id="alert_VotePg"></span>
```

Typescript File:

```
   var alertZ = document.getElementById('alert_VotePg');
   alertZ!.innerText ="1) Choose a movie 2) The name and email cannot be blank.";
```